# Docker Toolbox - default machine ip not connecting

Tags: docker, npm, webpack, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to run my react app in a docker container. I'm using Docker Toolbox because i have windows 10 home. When I run the image using the command "docker run -p 8080:8080 ${image_id}", everything works fine except I can't access the port, 192.168.99.104:8080.

When I try to access this in my browser, the port does not connect. I've tried accessing it through just 192.168.99.104 and going into the default virtual machine in VirtualBox to change to port mappings. None of those options have worked. The port exposed for the container shows that it is running on 0.0.0.0.8080->8080/tcp, so I assumed I would need to go to 192.168.99.104:8080.

When I print the app's output, I do not get errors either. The app output is

```
> bhm-slideshow@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js


> bhm-slideshow@0.1.0 watch-css /usr/src/app
> npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive


> bhm-slideshow@0.1.0 start-js /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start


> bhm-slideshow@0.1.0 build-css /usr/src/app
> node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/

> Rendering Complete, saving .css file...

> Wrote CSS to /usr/src/app/src/App.css

> Wrote 1 CSS files to /usr/src/app/src/

> => changed: /usr/src/app/src/App.scss

> Rendering Complete, saving .css file...

> Wrote CSS to /usr/src/app/src/App.css

> ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/

> ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from

> ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public

> ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /

> Starting the development server...

> Compiled with warnings.
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
#base image
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# bundle app's source code inside the Docker image, use COPY instruction
COPY . .


#define commands you want to run
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: can you please run `docker ps` and add the result here.